# Compare picture in Word file and in a folder?

Tags: c#, ms-word

So I'm using Word.Interloop and in order to compare two pics, I guess I have to transform the current picture(in word file) to a bitmap image and then compare it with a bitmap image object from desktop?
Or perhaps the is a simpler way to do so?

```
Word.InlineShape x;
x.isEqual( Picture from Desktop/ bitmapImage.Object);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a small sample showing how this can be accomplished. The main idea is to represent your image from your desktop as a `Bitmap` instance and then compare it pixel by pixel to the `Bitmap` instance in your document. The comparison is done by first copying an inline shape to the clipboard, then turning it into a `Bitmap`, and then compare it with the reference (from the desktop) - first by size and then pixel by pixel.

The sample is implemented as a C# console application using .NET 4.5, Microsoft Office Object Library version 15.0, and Microsoft Word Object Library version 15.0.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;

namespace WordDocStats
{
    class Program
    {
        // General idea is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937590/700926
        static void Main()
        {
            // Open a doc file
            var wordApplication = new Application();
            var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Username\Documents\document.docx");

            // Load the image to compare against.
            var bitmapToCompareAgainst = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Username\Documents\image.png");

            // For each inline shape, do a comparison
            // By inspection you can see that the first inline shape have index 1 ( and not zero as one might expect )
            for (var i = 1; i <= wordApplication.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count; i++)
            {
                // closure
                // http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure
                var inlineShapeId = i; 

                // parameterized thread start
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195915/700926
                var thread = new Thread(() => CompareInlineShapeAndBitmap(inlineShapeId, bitmapToCompareAgainst, wordApplication));

                // STA is needed in order to access the clipboard
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/518724/700926
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }

            // Close word
            wordApplication.Quit();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // General idea is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937590/700926
        protected static void CompareInlineShapeAndBitmap(int inlineShapeId, Bitmap bitmapToCompareAgainst, Application wordApplication)
        {
            // Get the shape, select, and copy it to the clipboard
            var inlineShape = wordApplication.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[inlineShapeId];
            inlineShape.Select();
            wordApplication.Selection.Copy();

            // Check data is in the clipboard
            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
            {
                var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                // Check if the data conforms to a bitmap format
                if (data != null && data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    // Fetch the image and convert it to a Bitmap
                    var image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
                    var currentBitmap = new Bitmap(image);
                    var imagesAreEqual = true;

                    // Compare the images - first by size and then pixel by pixel
                    // Based on: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp/
                    if(currentBitmap.Width == bitmapToCompareAgainst.Width && currentBitmap.Height == bitmapToCompareAgainst.Height)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < currentBitmap.Width; i++)
                        {
                            if(!imagesAreEqual)
                                break;

                            for (var j = 0; j < currentBitmap.Height; j++)
                            {
                                if (currentBitmap.GetPixel(i, j).Equals(bitmapToCompareAgainst.GetPixel(i, j)))
                                    continue;

                                imagesAreEqual = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imagesAreEqual = false;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Inline shape #{0} is equal to the 'external' bitmap: {1}", inlineShapeId, imagesAreEqual);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Clipboard data is not in an image format");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Clipboard is empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- Threadstart with params: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195915/700926
- Extracting inline shapes as images from word in C#:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937590/700926
- Comparing images in C#:
  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp/
- Details on how to retrieve an image from the clipboard in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/998825/700926
- Details on how to access the clipboard from C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/518724/700926