# How to get image data in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I have some problems with developing an add-in for MS Word. I need to get image data of pictures in the word document using C#. I know the method of [shape selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287908/save-pictures-from-word-to-folder-c-sharp) to the clipboard, but it seems to me like a hack. Is there any method to get image binary data from [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape(v=office.14).aspx) or [InlineShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape(v=office.14).aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip the docx file and list all images under ./word/media/.